# Printing more than the first row of array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

The code below scrapes two values from a webpage and adds them to an array. I've got as far as being able to print the first row of that array but I'm unable to get the whole thing.

I presume some sort of loop will be required but my attempts so far have been unsuccessful.

I feel this should be fairly basic. Any idea what I can do to achieve the desired result?

```
if(!empty($html)) {

    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); // remove errors for yucky html
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    /* FIND LINK TO PRODUCT PAGE */

    $products = array();

    $row = $xpath->query("$product_location");

    if ($row->length > 0) {

        foreach ($row as $location) {

            $products['product_url'] = $product_url_root.$location->getAttribute('href');
            $products['shop_name'] = $shop_name;

            $row = $xpath->query($photo_location);

            /* FIND LINK TO IMAGE */

            if ($row->length > 0) {

                foreach ($row as $location) {

                $products['photo_url'] = $photo_url_root.$location->getAttribute('src');

                }
            }
        }

            print_r($products);

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I should say that I'm hoping to get the array in this format:

```
Array (
    [0] {product_url => 123, shop_name => name, photo_url => abc}, 
    [1] {product_url => 456, shop_name => name, photo_url => def}, 
    [2] {product_url => 789, shop_name => name, photo_url => ghi}, 
    )
```

The plan is eventually to be able to use the following code in the place of `print_r($products)` to create an XML file:

```
$item = $channel->addChild("item");
$item->addChild("product_url", $entry['product_url']);
$item->addChild("shop_name", $entry['shop_name']);
$item->addChild("photo_url", $entry['photo_url']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the following details to create the associative array you need:

- the product URL
- the shop name
- the product image URL

Now, in your code, you're looping through the product URLs — and **for each product URL, you're looping through the list of product image URLs**. This will cause the code inside the nested `foreach` to be executed n^2 times. You do not want that.

Here's how you should structure your loops:

```
/* Create an array containing products */
if ($row->length > 0)
{            
    foreach ($row as $location)
    {
        $product_urls[] = $product_url_root . $location->getAttribute('href');
    }
}
$imgs = $xpath->query($photo_location);

/* Create an array containing the image links */
if ($imgs->length > 0)
{            
    foreach ($imgs as $img)
    {
        $photo_url[] = $photo_url_root . $img->getAttribute('src');
    }
}


$result = array();

/* Create an associative array containing all the above values */
foreach ($product_urls as $i => $product_url)
{
    $result[] = array(
        'product_url' => $product_url,
        'shop_name' => $shop_name,
        'photo_url' => $photo_url[$i]
    );
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does the same go for $products['product_url'] anc $products['shop_name'] in the first foreach loop?

Comment: I've changed it and now I'm getting this, which isn't quite the desired result: http://www.comfyshoulderrest.com/simplescrape.php?id=1

Comment: @user3423062: Add `<pre>` tag before `<?php ...`. Like so: `<pre><?php ...`.

Comment: Done, it looks like it's grouping them by each attribute rather than each element, if you see what I mean. (Just seen your edit, really useful explanation of what my initial mistake was, thanks.)

Take a look at my edit for what I'm trying to achieve